# How do you change print margins with Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, printing, bootstrap-4

I'm building a simple, one-page app using Vue in Laravel. I'm using Bootstrap 4 for general styling. The content of the app is supposed to be printed out, so I'd like to modify the left margin for print only to accommodate a hole punch - that is, increase it to 1". Everything else can remain the same.

Since this is such a small change, I'm trying to do it using an embedded style sheet that I load after vanilla Bootstrap, but nothing I add seems to make a difference. Here's the top of my Blade template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <style>
      [v-cloak] {
        display: none;
      }
      @media print{
        @page {
          size: letter;
          margin: 3cm;
        }
        html, body {
          width: 1024px;
        }
        .container {
          width: auto;
        }
        body {
          margin: 0 auto;
        }
      }
    </style>

    <!-- Vue.js for development -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

    <title>NTI Daily Checklist</title>
  </head>

...
```

I think I've added a 3cm margin all around the page, but Chrome's print preview still shows the narrow default print margin. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you open the print window the margin dropdown had the value `Default` or `Custom` ? because in order for styles to take effect it should be `Custom`

Comment: I checked, and the margins were set to Custom. I changed them to Default, and the print preview changed. It wasn't exactly what I expected, but it's something to play with. Thanks for the suggestion!